# Emacs doesn't use ~/.ssh/config when accessing files on a remote machine

Tags: ssh, emacs, arch-linux

I have a fresh install of arch Linux. I've installed Emacs from the rpos, and my home directory is mounted from a separate partition. I have old settings I've used on my `~/.ssh/config` along with authentication keys I've regularly used before. Now, when I try to connect to a remote machine using Emacs, Emacs asks for my password and uses the wrong username. Clearly, Emacs doesn't access my config file. When I try to `ssh` or `scp` directly to the machine, things work fine. What do I need to update?

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure that you use the same hostname as in the config file?

Comment: Yes. I've figured the problem. I had to update tramp default protocol.

Comment: In that case, please post an answer explaining what you had to do and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Tramp default protocol was `ftp` and not `ssh`. I've updated it via Emacs gui setting interface and had to restart Emacs.

Edit:

`M-x RET customize-option RET tramp-default-method`

I remember I've changed `ftp` to `ssh` there but now I see `scpc`. Perhaps I've installed ssh after launching Emacs.

Comment: This isn't a useful answer at the moment, but will be if you add some information on how you went about updating it.

Comment: Good edit! The `scpc` method uses the SSH ControlMaster option to establish an SSH connection and then reuse it for each SCP transfer, which is in my experience more efficient than establishing a new SSH socket for each transfer, as IIRC the `ssh` method does; you might want to give `scpc` a try -- after all, if it doesn't work, you can always switch back to `ssh`.